# Are Scientists (& Astronomers) able to see the Same Distance away from Earth (or Solar System) in all Directions?

Tags: universe

Thinking about the Universe being shaped like a huge ball , & given that we are not in the center because there is no center : When Scientists (& Astronomers) look out in various Directions , though various tools , is the Distance Measurement almost same for the farthest Entities ?

Pictorially,

Let us say , Earth (& Solar System) is at the Crossing in the Purple Area, which is the Partially known Universe.
The Inner Circle is the "Edge" of the Partially Known Universe.
The White Area is the Knowable Universe , when newer tools are available in the future.
The Outer Grey Area is the Unknowable Void beyond the Known Universe.
We have Entities (Star Systems , galaxies , black holes , Inter-galactic gases) on the Edge of the Partially Known Universe.

Looking at Entity 1 : We currently measure Distance D.
Looking at Entity 2 : Do we measure Distance D (APPROX) ?
Looking at Entity 3 : Do we measure Distance D (APPROX) ?
Looking at Entity 4 : Do we measure Distance D (APPROX) ?

I am asking about all 3 Dimensional Directions.

[image: Earth + Universe]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background

Comment: Also see [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)

Comment: Yes , CMB is same in every Direction. It is similar to (but not same as) what I want to know about Star Systems , galaxies , black holes or Inter-galactic gases. Yes , we are not in the center of the universe (the first line of my Post) but it generally looks like that & it will always look like that in every galaxy. What I am asking : Are the farthest entities (seen in various Directions) all at the same APPROX Distance ? Or is some Direction "shorter" while some other Direction is "longer" ? Imagine living on some island & seeing rocks at 200 km East & seeing Islands at 800 km West. @PM2Ring

Comment: The CMB is the furthest thing we can see, at a redshift distance of z ~ 1089, in all directions.